# Random number generator with no duplicate

Tags: android, arrays, random, textview, generator

I am having a hard time trying to ensure no duplicates numbers appear in the following code below. I tried to create an ArrayList to add all the possible index of the array and then gradually remove the values of the array from the List as more elements are generated by the number generator. This; however, didnt work as I expected. I've been trying to think about it but Haven't been able to come up with a viable solution.

```
Random randGen = new Random();
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {

switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        x1 = touchevent.getX();
        y1 = touchevent.getY();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        x2 = touchevent.getX();
        y2 = touchevent.getY();


        int maxLength=exampleArray.length;
        List<Integer>indices=new ArrayList<Integer>(maxLength);
        for(int i=0;i<maxLength;i++){
            indices.add(i);
        }

        int randomApple = randGen.nextInt(exampleArray.length);
        int randomNum=indices.get(randomApple)  ;
        indices.remove(randomApple);
        textView.setText(exampleArray[randomNum]);

        if (x1 < x2) {

        }

        if (x1 > x2) {

            //textView.setText(exampleArray[randomNum]);

        }

    }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/how-to-generate-a-list-of-unique-random-strings/1390#1390) for three ways to generate non-repeating random numbers in different situations.

Comment: i like everyones answers, but Im curious why the solution I thought was correct doesnt work

Comment: You are generating a whole new `indices` list for each `ACTION-UP`.  If you don't want duplicates across different events, then you will have to store either used or unused numbers across different events to avoid duplicates across events.

Comment: I think I get what you mean. Thanks for the suggestion. Your saying that each time ACTION_UP is used, a new indices list is used, right? To rectify this, would you suggest moving the indices list globally?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some steps and adding extraneous ones....

One simple way (if you don't care whether the numbers keep going up) is to keep adding a random positive value to a counter. That way the new counter will always be different.

If you do:
Another way to do this is to creating a list of numbers beforehand (either sequentially [1, 2, 3...] or you randomly add some amount to each new index [rnd1, rnd1 + rnd2, rnd1 + rnd2 + rnd3...]), randomizing the ordering by [shuffling the numbers (click this!)](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/), and then simply iterating through the created array.

Comment: While the link was interesting, I see no practical need to reinvent [Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Comment: I feel like it should work thought. First, I added in all the possible index[ 0 through max] and then used a random number generator to obtain a number. And then, removed that number from the Arraylist created, thus, preventing the usage of the same elements twice.

Comment: How do you ensure that the random number generator created a number which exists in your array?